# Hexdigest and diges SHA1

Tags: java, hex, sha1, sha

Как мне можно получить sha1 без hex, сейчас использую простой

```
DigestUtils.sha("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes())
```

выдает

> 2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12

а надо чтобы выдавал

> '/\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12'

на питоне это выходит вот так

```
stri = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

ash = hashlib.sha1()
ash.update(stri)
ash.digest()
```

> '/\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12'

```
ash.hexdigest()
```

> '2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12'

Comment: во-первых `sha()` - устарело, во вторых почему вы решили что возвращается hex?

Comment: я не знаю что это значит, но мне нужен результат как в питоне, при  hexdigest() выдает '2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12' а при digest()  возвращает >/\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, вашу цель. У меня складывается ощущение, что я ответил не на тот вопрос, на который вы хотели получить ответ. См. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710/177613

Comment: я хочу получить sha такого вида '/\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12' а не '2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12', такая функция есть на питоне но не могу найти такой для java

Comment: Еще раз дополнил ответ. Вы все-таки что-то скрываете :) Никак не пойму, зачем нужна именно такая строка.

Comment: так шифруется пароль у одного из компаний куда мне надо обращаться, у них питон так шифрует

Comment: Обратите внимание, что возможно Python выдает бинарную строку, а hex-эскейпинг получается при её выводе на терминал. Хотя возможно какой-то странный человек пишет, например в базу, именно такое значение. Кстати моё последнее дополнение вам помогло?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Боюсь, вы ошибаетесь. `DigestUtils.sha()` возвращает строку или массив байт, содержащие хеш **без** преобразования.

Вот набросал пример (**исправлено**):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] digest;
        digest = DigestUtils.sha("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        System.out.println(new String(digest));
    }
}
```

Вот что в результате:

```
C:\usr\project\my\java-digestutils>javac Test.java
Note: Test.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Тут собственно речь о том, что `sha()` слегка несвежий (надо использовать `sha1` или `sha256`, `sha384`, `sha512` - по вкусу)

```
C:\usr\project\my\java-digestutils>java Test
/ФбЖz-(ьн??б?vз9←?л↕
```

Это в cp1251. Если сохранить результат в файл и посмотреть в hex-виде:

```
0000000000: 2F D4 E1 C6 7A 2D 28 FC │ ED 84 9E E1 BB 76 E7 39  /ФбЖz-(ьн„ћб»vз9
0000000010: 1B 93 EB 12 0D 0A       │                          ←“л↕♪◙
```

**Дополнено**
Если нужно получить результат аналогичный результату на Python, то нужно использовать `sha1()`. Получится такой же резльтат, который продемонстрирован выше. Для сравнения:

```
import hashlib

stri = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
ash = hashlib.sha1()
ash.update(stri)
print ash.digest()
```

Выдает:

> /╘с╞z-(№эДЮс╗vч9←Уы↕

Разница в отображаемых строках вызвана различиями кодировки консоли. Если вы хотите, чтобы непечатаемые символы были отображены как в Python (например '\xd4\xe1'), дополнительно придется экранировать эти символы.

**Еще раз дополнено**
Чтобы экранировать символы, не входящие в `latin1` придется писать свою функцию. Допустим добавим в наш класс вот такой метод:

```
public static StringBuffer escapeNonPrintable(byte[] byteArray) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : byteArray) {
        if (b < 32 || b > 127) {
            result.append(String.format("\\x%02x", b));
        } else {
            result.append((char)b);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Теперь перепишем `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] digest;
    digest = DigestUtils.sha1("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
    System.out.println(escapeNonPrintable(digest));
}
```

В результате:

> /\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12

Comment: я пытался использовать и другие версии sha256 b 512  у меня не выходит /\xd4\xe1\xc6z-(\xfc\xed\x84\x9e\xe1\xbbv\xe79\x1b\x93\xeb\x12

Comment: @JTan Другие версии однозначно не дадут такого результата. Это же другие хеш-функции. Если вам нужен аналог `sha()` это `sha1()`. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это то что надо, использую DigestUtils.sha